# How to split string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have string - **`Normal content<code>Add your code here</code>Normal content<code>Add your code here</code>`**

How to split this string into separate part so that I can get -

1. Normal content
2. `<code>Add your code here</code>`
3. Normal content
4. `<code>Add your code here</code>`

Comment: "krupesh,kotecha".split(",");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var yourString="Normal content<code>Add your code here</code>Normal content<code>Add your code here</code>";

var arrResult=yourString.replace(/\<code\>/g,'#<code>').replace(/\<\/code\>/g,'</code>#').split("#");
```

try this.

Comment: You shouldn't use the char `#` to split the string, it's a too common character. Try to use custom sentence like  : `$$MYSEPARATOR$$`
`var arrResult=yourString.replace(/\<code\>/g,'$$MYSEPARATOR$$<code>').replace(/\<\/code\>/g,'</code>$$MYSEPARATOR$$').split("$$MYSEPARATOR$$");

Comment: @San: Hey, thanks a lot. Nice logic.